# Pacing Time Calculation and Iteration time in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Vusers =10, duration = 1hour, TPH = 250 and No.of Transactions = 6

How to calculate the  Pacing time and iteration time please?

Could anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

"Pacing" is something from the world of basic tools which don't have smarter way of pausing the threads to limit the throughput for the given value.

In JMeter you have the choice of:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

The latter one is even capable of kicking off extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient to reach and maintain the desired throughput if it's used in conjunction with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)